# Use JFrame as a custom input box

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a java swing based application where i have two `JFrames`: `A`, which is the main window, and `B`, which is called on `A`.

What i need to do is to, in `A`, call `B`, get user input from `B` and pass that input to `A` somehow, to then proccess it

Everything I've tried has failed, and as far as I know Java doesn't support `async/await`

This is my best attempt

```java
    public void getInfoFromB()
    {
        FormB b = new FormB();

        while(b.isReady() == false){
            a.setVisible(false);
        }

        a.setVisible(true);
        ArrayList<String> b.getData();

        //...
    }
```

Note that both `a` and `b` objects extends `JFrame`, `FormB`'s isReady is a method that returns weathers the user has filled in all the data needed, and getData method returns said data

This attempt doesn't seem to work because once the code enters the while loop,  everything else just freezes, as java seems to struggle with parallel actions

Comment: Have B signal to A when ready, passing any information that is needed in A. That would involve passing a reference to A when creating form B. Note also, that anything GUI related in Swing is single-threaded.

Comment: you mean passing a pointer to A to B? That is actually a great idea, i hope java supports pointers

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers, but any object is referred to be a reference. Meaning, if you do `A a = new A()`, a will hold a reference to the object you created. Pass that reference to the B instance (by way of construction for instance, or a method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @TT., it is possible to pass A to B by reference (Apparently all objects are passed by reference, so there's no need to use pointers). From there, i could manipulate data from both A and B

Class A

```java
public void getDataFromB(ArrayList<String> data)
{
    this.dataFromB = data;
}

public void startFormB()
{
    this.setVisible(false);
    B formB = new B(this);
}
```

Class B

```java
//constructor
public B(formA a)
{
    this.mainForm = a;

    //...
}


public void setDataToAAndExit()
{
    this.mainForm.getDataFromB(this.dataToA);
    //re-show main window
    this.mainForm.setVisible(true);
    //close this window
    this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just use a `JOptionPane` to prompt for the input.

The main frame will wait until the option pane is closed in order to get the text entered by the user.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Getting User Input From a Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) for more information and examples.

Comment: the problem is that the kind of data i need can't be input from a JOptionPane

Comment: Why not? There are many ways to use a JOptionPane. You can provide a list of Strings/Components to add to the option pane. You can provide a custom panel with multiple components, You can add your own PropertyChangeListener to prevent the dialog from closing unless data has been entered in all fields. Read the tutorial. Even if you don't want to use the JOptionPane you can still use a `modal JDialog` and add your custom panel to the dialog. Don't try to create your own looping/polling code to wait for a user to enter data.

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Dude, i need to display 3 text boxes and a whole data table, and a label that has it's content's refreshed every time said table is clicked or one of the text boxes's value changes. Even if it was possible to be done in a JOptionPane, the secondary JFrame solution worked just fine. I mean, i didn't know about the JDialog, which seems interesting, but in the end i needed to do more than just user input in that new JFrame (such as database operations).

Comment: Look Dude1  All your question stated was you needed user input. The obvious answer is to use a JOption pane for a single piece of data. Or you could even use a JOption pane with a panel containing multiple components. It is still easier than creating your own window because all the code for handling the "OK" "Cancel" buttons is built in. Or if you don't like that then you create a custom JDialog. An application should only have a single JFrame. All child windows should be dialogs. This is standard Swing design. Don't reinvent the wheel now that you know about a JDialog!